# foreach binding doesn't apply parent context for click

Tags: knockout.js

So my foreach binding works as expected except for the child elements click binding the context isn't applied. Since the openFolder function is in my ViewModel and not the Folder, i would've expected to have to use $parent.openFolder to access it, but that doesn't work (it works if i do it without the $parent though). Here's the relevant code:

index.html

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: folders">
    <li>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: openFolder">  <!-- I would've expected $parent.openFolder here -->
            <span data-bind="text: folderName"></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

main.js

```
function Folder(name) {
    this.folderName = ko.observable(name);
}

function MyModel() {
    self.folders = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.openFolder = function() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

so my question is, why is the context for the click binding not changed to the folder context?

Comment: is this the complete code for your models, or have you left out any parts?

Comment: i've left out most of my code (the working parts) and just kept the most relevant parts to post here. the question has been answered already. thanks for trying to help.

Comment: i had spotted the wrong declarations of self, like HeyJude suggested, i just did not want to post it in case you had just stripped some code.
Your problem is that by not declaring self, you had everything declared on the global window object, thats why the bind engine did find the objects to make your bindings work. Dont forget to assign references :D have a good day

Comment: alright so the assumption i made in the other comment was correct. thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to declare `self`:

```
function Folder(name) {
    var self = this;
    self.folderName = ko.observable(name);
}
function MyModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.folders = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.openFolder = function() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right :D that did the trick. Thanks. Now just so i understand this correctly... if i don't assign self to this it has the value of window.self so the function openFolder is therefore defined in the window's context and not in the model and as a result not availabe in the parent of folder?